# Kaggle Exercise: Missing Values

Tags: artificial-intelligence, linear-regression, random-forest, kaggle

I am trying to submit my solution to [Exercise: Missing Values](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/intermediate-machine-learning) but getting the following error after submission

ERROR: Unable to find 1459 required key values in the 'Id' column

ERROR: Unable to find the required key value '1461' in the 'Id' column
.
.
.

ERROR: Unable to find the required key value '1469' in the 'Id' column

The thing is that the test dataset only has 1459 rows, from the error it seems like validation set expecting more entries?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to `output/submission.csv`, you'll notice that the `Id` starts at `0`. Then look at `input/sample_submission.csv` and notice that it's `Id` starts at `1461`, which is what the competition is expecting. The original test data starts at `1461`. What likely happened is that you lost the original `Id` numbers in the test `DataFrame` used to write the output. 
You can fix it like this:

```py
output = pd.DataFrame({'Id': X_test.index,
                       'SalePrice': preds_test})
```

`X_Test` contains your original `Id` numbers and will ensure your output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the csv file at the beginning look that you put the `index_col='Id'` parameter.

```
df_train_full = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/.../train.csv", index_col='Id')

df_test_full = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/.../test.csv", index_col='Id')
```

Comment: I checked but I already have that so this does not seem to be the issue, I can share the whole solution if that will help, please share your kaggle Id.